# Switching themes in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to setup my app so it has 2 different themes, one for admin and one for the client.

So in my app.component I've have

```
<div class="wrapper" [ngSwitch]="themeService.getTheme()">
  <app-client-layout *ngSwitchCase="'client'"></app-client-layout>
  <app-admin-layout *ngSwitchCase="'admin'"></app-admin-layout>
</div>
```

Then the layouts are

client

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="page">
  <h1>Client</h1>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

admin

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="page">
  <h1>Admin</h1>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The problem with this is the router-outlet doesn't work. I'm sure there must be a way of doing this but struggling to find any examples of the best approach.

Comment: What I did was define two html layouts with a single router-outlet and use an ngIf statement based on a Boolean value in the app component.  Works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry struggling to see how I can use ngIf as router-outlet doesn't work the same as ngSwitch doesn't and I'm trying to wrap the router-outlet with markup specific to that theme. I think I'm just thinking about it in the wrong way

Comment: HTML for client with ngIf = "client"; HTML for admin with ngIf="!client"; <router-outlet></router-outlet>.  Then set the client property in the app component as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is actual code from my app.  I switch menu display based on a loggedIn observable in the app.component.

```
<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-grid-pad">
    <div class="ui-g borderDiv" [ngStyle]="appPageHeaderDivStyle">
        <div class="ui-g-12" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-lg-3 ui-xl-2">
                    <img class="logo" src="./app/resources/KetoLightLogo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-lg-5 ui-xl-7">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-lg-4 ui-xl-3 ui-g-nopad" style="width: 320px; margin-left: 80px; float: right; ">
                    <div>
                        <p-menubar class="pMenuBar" [model]="items"></p-menubar>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-g-12" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-lg-2 ui-xl-2">
                    <img class="logo" src="assets/KetoLightLogo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-lg-3 ui-xl-4">
                    <label class="ui-widget loggedInLabel">Logged in as: Me </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-lg-6 ui-xl-6 ui-g-nopad menuStyle" >
                    <p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Hope this helpls.  There is a lot more html on that page, this is just to show you what I'm talking about.

Comment: OK think maybe we're not on the same page. I understand what you mean about changing parts of the template like you've shown but what I'm trying to do is use 2 completely different templates i.e my admin will be bootstrap and client will be custom. It's most likely that the 2 templates will need different markup wrapped around the router-outlet.

Comment: Okay.. I'm not following... Why can you not put both templates into one?  Then instead of fighting ng2 to pigeon-hole it, you can get on with development.

Comment: So should the following work
`<div class="client" *ngIf="isClient">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>Client</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="admin" *ngIf="!isClient">
    <h1>Admin</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>`
as I'm finding it not always loading content into the router-oulet, but if I move router-outlet outside of the ngif it does load. Everything works apart from having router-oulet inside an ngif

Comment: You can't use 2 router-outlets with the same name.  Look at Named route-outlets.